# Setting up react-router in a Flux application

Tags: reactjs-flux, flux, react-router, reactjs

I have a React application where `main.js` calls `app.js`--which acts as a parent component--as can be seen here:

```
React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

Now I need to set up [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) so that `app.js` will handle routing within the app.

## Present setup

To set up my routes I have created `routes.js`, which contains the following code:

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route path="/" handler={home}/>
  </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

In `app.js` I imported routes and added `RouteHandler` as in the documentation:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('../routes.js');
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var APP = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <RouteHandler/>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = APP;
```

I am having trouble understanding this code in the documentation:

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
});
```

Since I have already called the `<app />` component from within the `main` component I want to handle all of the routing in the `app` component. I think the above code is transferring `handler={component_to_render}` through `Root`. But how do I configure my code in `app.js` to transfer the route to `<RouteHandler/>`?

My whole setup might be wrong, so any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: It should works, what's the problem ? The syntax you do not understand is a ES6 syntax called [ArrowFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), it's a shortcut for writing `function(Root){ return React.render(<Root/>, document.body) })`

Comment: i am rendering "app" component from "main component", i intend to use route in "main" component but not in "app" component. To explain further, i intend all of the route to effect "main" component  and render new component according to what ever route is passed. 
For example, if this route is triggered <Route path="/" handler={home}/> , i want to load "home" component in "main.js. Now i am not sure where Router.run.... code goes and i do not intend to use React.render(<Root/>, document.body) inside Router.run function, i just need to effect app.js from what ever route is triggered in routes.js

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but I noticed a problem: you are importing `routes.js` as React Router rather than importing the actual React Router in `app.js`. You need to `require` React Router and the routes independently: `var Router = require('react-router')` and `var routes = require('../routes.js');`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Router` has to know which component to render, it has to be the root component. So instead of writing...

```
React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

...just write that :

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById("main"));
});
```

When some user hits the "/" url, the `<Root/>` node will render your `APP` handler which in turns will render your `HomeComponent`.

Comment: what if i am using 
'React.render(<app/>, document.getElementById("main"));' in main.js  to render app component in app.js and now i want to render /(root) or whatever route  inside app.js but not main.js. I have  <RouteHandler/> inside app.js but now how do i listen to URL and render component inside app.js. And also i can not use this code to listen to url as this code has [  document.getElementById("main"));    ]

code: 
Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById("main"));
});

Comment: For example, let's say you have a "public" app and a "admin" app so you want different route for both, that's the kind of think you're looking for ?